# Should yum update <package-name> resolve dependencies?

Tags: yum

I have foo-1.1 and foo-devel-1.1 both installed. Now I update my repo with foo-1.2 and foo-devel-1.2. After `yum clean metadata`, I simply type `yum update`, no problem. I get both foo-1.2 and foo-devel-1.2 reported as ready to update.

However, if I type `yum update foo-devel` the related *foo* dependency is **not** reported as ready to update. Is this correct behavior? How do I get the behavior I'm expecting? Which is that all dependencies resolve and update when a package name is specified as an argument to yum update.

`$rpm -q yum`

yum-3.2.29-43.el6_5.noarch

Thanks for any info!

-Fin

Comment: Yum calculates the dependencies based on the `Requires` of `rpm` packages. Yum has nothing to do with what the packages require or don't require. You can query foo and foo-devel to actually see if they require the other by running `rpm -q --whatrequires foo` and `rpm -q --whatrequires foo-devel`. If none of them required the other then yum will definitely not update the other.

Comment: Sure. My foo.spec has %package devel  Requires: foo  ...  This is also confirmed with `rpm -q --whatrequires foo`   So, again, my expectation is that `yum update foo-devel` will also update new versions of foo. Do you agree? Indeed, I get the expected behavior when I simply type `yum update`. Notice there's no argument to update in the latter.

Comment: I updated my 2nd para to improve clarity.

Comment: Do you have a version lock for foo-devel ? You can also do `yum clean all`

Comment: The `Requires` in the spec file may not be versioned. If it isn't versioned then the the dependencies is still satisfied without updating the required package. Try to change it to require specific version. You can specify in `foo-devel` spec file put it like `Requires: foo = %{version}-%{release}`. This will ensure that when `foo-devel` is upgraded, so will `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When updating all packages**

`yum update` will update any packages that have a newer version available, and take care of dependencies.

From the manual page `man yum`:

`While updating packages, yum will ensure that all dependencies are satisfied.`

One thing to bear in mind is that while a package may have an update available, that does not mean that a dependency of that package has been updated too - they are after all seperate packages.

**When updating a specific package**

From the manual: `If one or more packages or package globs are specified, Yum will only update the listed packages.`
This seems to imply that if foo-devel requires foo, and you specify to update only foo-devel, then yum won't update foo to a newer version (unless foo-devel specifically requires the newer version).